# Map of Strings and value across distributed machines, what is string with most value?

Tags: algorithm, hash, distributed-computing

We've maps with string and positive integer as key/value pair in different distributed machines.
We need to find out the String with highest value across all the servers.

We should avoid transferring the entire maps from all the locations, as it is costly and contradicts the distributed nature.

Is there a way to optimally solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you require the right answer? Or are you content with "probably the largest"?

Comment: I would like to hear both too

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a textbook [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) problem. You'd need to have a master which collects information from all the nodes. Each node must report its largest string/value item to the master. The master can simply then decide who had the string with the largest value.

Comment: Let's say one node reports that "A" is the max, and another node reports that "B" is the max, and etc.  We will end up querying the most of the map.

Comment: I think we still need some efficient algorithm. Using MapReduce will contradict with the restriction that we cannot transfer entire map.

Comment: You're not transferring the entire map, only the max of each node. The only way to can improve on this algorithm is if there is a pattern in the construction of the map that allows you to make prediction of which node does *not* have the max so you know not to query it.

Comment: Let's say I have 3 nodes, with node 1 containing Strings A --> 4 B-->4 C -->5, Node 2 containing String B--> 4 A->3 C-->0 , And Node 3 containing C->2 B->2, A->2  You still need to transfer all of them

Comment: ahhh, the strings aren't exclusively distributed to a single node. I wrongly assumed that was implied in the question.

Comment: Yes, the question is still open :(